# Що означає слово "бав’янець"?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники

Прочитала пісню [«По горі, горі павоньки ходять»](http://proridne.com/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96/%D0%9F%D0%9E_%D0%93%D0%9E%D0%A0%D0%86,_%D0%93%D0%9E%D0%A0%D0%86_%D0%9F%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E%D0%9D%D0%AC%D0%9A%D0%98_%D0%A5%D0%9E%D0%94%D0%AF%D0%A2%D0%AC.html), і там натрапила на слово **бав’янець**. Інформації ні в СУМі-11, ні в СУМі-20 нема. В Етимологічному словнику теж немає. Аби зрозуміти контекст, наводжу:

> Зірвали вінець, вінець-**бав’янець**,
>
> Занесли єго в тихий Дунаєць.

Отож що означає слово ***бав’янець***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У цьому ж збірнику знаходимо варіант цієї ж колядки, з трохи зміненим текстом [«По горі, горі пава літала»](http://proridne.com/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%20%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96/index%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%9F.html)

> Ізвіялися буйні вітрове
>
> Та й зашайнули **пав’яний вінчик**,
>
> Та й зашайнули в краї Дунаї.

Оскільки, зміст цих пісень однаковий, то можна припустити , що у колядці ***«По горі, горі павоньки ходять»*** **вінець-бав’янець=пав’яний вінчик**.

Це пов’язано з тим, що ([Вінок](http://about-ukraine.com/vinok-1762/)) :

> Пір’яні весільні вінки побутували в багатьох народів. Це пов’язано з уявленнями про подібність душі й дівчини загалом до пташки. *Для колядок є характерним мотив, коли по горі ходять пави, а за ними — панна. Вона збирає павине пір’я, складає його в рукав, згодом розкладає на столі і плете собі з того пір’я вінок.* Коли ж кладе його собі на голову — десь беруться “буйні вітрове”, здіймають вінок і несуть хтозна-куди.

Отже, цілком логічно, враховуючи варіанти цієї пісні, можна припустити, що **вінець-пав’янець=вінець, зроблений з пав’яного пір’я**, що випливає із самого контексту колядки.